# cumulative sum error in scala - recursive value needs type

Tags: scala, recursion

i am trying to do a simple accumulative sum below in scala , but it is giving me an error - recursive value needs type. how can i fix this

```
val numIter = 20
val total_duration = 0


for {i <- 0 until numIter } {
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  val df_left_joined2 = df2.join(df_s2, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
  val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d
  val total_duration = total_duration + duration
  println(total_duration)}
```

error: recursive value total_duration needs type

i tried to define the variable type by following, it gives me a different error

```
val numIter = 20
val total_duration: Double = 0

for {i <- 0 until numIter } {
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  val df_left_joined2 = df2.join(df_s2, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
  val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d
  val total_duration: Double = total_duration + duration
  println(total_duration)}
```

error: forward reference extends over definition of value total_duration

Comment: If `val x = x + 2` then what is the value of `x`? It makes no sense. Your 2nd definition of `total_duration` is shadowing the 1st.

Comment: you don't want the `val` in the second `total_duration`, in the for . Also I believe 1e9d should be written as `0x1e9d` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> val total_duration = total_duration + duration

You are redefining the constant `total_duration`, hence the error message.

It looks like what you want to do instead, is using a `var`:

```scala
var total_duration = 0
```

And the line `val total_duration = total_duration + duration` becomes :

```scala
total_duration = total_duration + duration
```

Comment: val numIter = 20
var total_duration = 0

for {i <- 0 until numIter } {
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  val df_left_joined2 = df2.join(df_s2, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
  val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d
  total_duration = total_duration + duration
  println(total_duration)}

Comment: after i update that, it give me a different error: <console>:49: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Double): ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method int2long in object Int of type (x: Int)Long
 and method int2float in object Int of type (x: Int)Float
 are possible conversion functions from Int to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Double): ?}
         total_duration = total_duration + duration
                          ^

Comment: You need to declare `total_duration` as a `Double` --> `var total_duration: Double = 0`, else it is inferred as an `Int`